# How to bind feature file and step definition in Visual studio code for Python Behave?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, gherkin, python-behave

I am unable to bind feature file and step definition in visual studio code for Python behave.
When I right click on step definition. It says "no definition found for 'given'"
Please find the attached screenshot.

[No definition found for given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRs5h.png)

Also, when I try to run through terminal it says "No steps directory in the specified path".
Is there any problem with folder structure ?
Please help me to solve these two issues.

I tried below steps:
-Tried to follow the folder structure as below:
[folder structure for behave in visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb3dm.png)

- Installed different extensions for Python behave(Cucumber, Cucumber Gherkin Full support)

For running the feature file in Terminal of visual studio, used this command "behave features\newcode.feature"
When I do that I get the message as "No steps directory in specified path"

Comment: what is the reason of `settings.json` in your steps folder, can you give the py file in `steps` **any* name? what if you execute `trialcode.py` as a standalone, do the imports work

Comment: From your image, it seems that the import of the first line in trailcode.py does not work. At the same time, please place the `settings.json` file in the `.vscode` folder under the workspace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

From your image, it seems that the import of the first line in trailcode.py does not work. You have to check and solve this problem.

At the same time, please place the `settings.json` file in the `.vscode` folder under the workspace.